# R warning: " 'package:stats' may not be available when loading"

Tags: r, package, warnings, loading, rstudio

I've been working with the `arules` package and `RODBC` package for a few days now in RStudio. I saved the workspace image multiple times in the meantime. But today I wanted to save my workspace image again and now I get this warning:

> Warning message:
>   In save(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE), file = outfile,  :
>     'package:stats' may not be available when loading

I only used `arules` and `RODBC` functions and `str_split_fixed` from `stringr` and some standard stuff like `data.frame`. 
I didn't even use the `stats` package at all. When reloading the workspace image, it doesn't seem affected by it. But the warning is bothering me anyway, especially since `stats` is supposed to be a standard package of R, how can it be unavailable... How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: This is a bug in RStudio itself (there is some internal code run that uses `stats::setNames()` when saving the environment, which can trigger this warning). It will go away in the next (preview) release, but for now you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @KevinUshey Thanks, that's a relief.

Comment: Sorry to drag up an old thread @KevinUshey, but I am still experiencing this issue when using RStudio Version 0.99.435 and R 3.2.0.

Comment: @Kevin Experiencing this message isn’t restricted to working with RStudio.

Comment: @KevinUshey Experienced the same error in multiple sessions trying to save a function to .R file. RStudio version 1.0.44, R version 3.3.2. File is created but appears corrupted.

Comment: Its the end of 2018 and Im experiencing this issue in RStudio 1.2.192

Comment: In the end of 2023 I got this issue in R version 4.3.1, RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea", 2023-07-07.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the commentator didn't post his comment as an answer, I will close this question myself: it's a bug in RStudio and knowing this thanks to SO I could close down RStudio and a couple R programming sessions later the warning message did not occur again.

Answer (score 0):

This is now an [official rstudio bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7001#issue-627302035).

In my case (the repro in the bug) the root cause was that one of the objects I was trying to save referenced an rstudio-internal function (this isn’t very exotic. A plain `options` call returns a list that does that). RStudio functions live in tools:rstudio namespace, which inherits the stats package among others - hence the warning.

It is currently planned to be fixed as part of v1.4.